# In swift, clicking a button does not activate the action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am working on a simple IPhone application in Xcode 7, and i need to save some data so that i can then load it in a table view.

The data is entered via a dedicated view that possess some input fields and two buttons : "Save" which save the data into an object, then puts that object in a list and "Cancel" which simply returns to the last screen.

The problem is : **Any use of the save button seems to not be recognized.** I have tried multiple times to print something out of clicking that button and nothing ever prints.

My Code :

- Button Action

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? DataViewController,
        let dataObject = sourceViewController.dataObject{

            // Add new data - not really important for the question i guess
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: dataList.count, section: 0)
            dataList.append(dataObject)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)


    }

    // Never prints anything
    os_log("DEBUG", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

}
```

- Prepare - Data preparation

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        guard let button = sender as? UIButton, button === saveButton else {

         // This one activates when we press "Cancel"
         os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return
        }

       //Data object field filling lines

        let foo= nameTextField.foo ?? ""

        dataObject= Data(foo: foo)

    }
```

- Screenshot of Action Hook
  [image: UnwindToLocationView() is buttonAction()]

  > UnwindToLocationView() is buttonAction()

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of how the actions are hooked in the storyboard

Comment: Have you hooked up your save button in the storyboard?

Comment: I dont think is a hook issue, he has the segue as sender which is actually a button

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 the `IBAction`s must have an underscore character as the external parameter name

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
```

Answer (score 0):

And the sender should probably be your button:

```
 @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

This is a sample of prepare for segue

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" , 
           let nextScene = segue.destination as? DetailController , 
           let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let selectedData = data[indexPath.row]
            nextScene.currentData = selectedData
        }
    }
```